# Express get request with an :id-parameter being run twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I have an API made with node and express, and the end goal is to store the :id-parameter from the request in a variable so that I can query a specific table from my SQLite database with a specific id. Now the get request with an :id-parameter is being run twice, once with the request url being what it´s supposed to be (in my case "page") and once with the url /serviceWorker.js.

This is the code from my router with the get-request:

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/:id", function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log("id:", id);
  console.log("Req url:", req.url);
  res.send(id);
});

export default router
```

The console log from a single get request looks like this:

```
id: molekylverkstan
Req url: /molekylverkstan
id: serviceWorker.js
Req url: /serviceWorker.js
```

Even when running the get request for my home page, with this code:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("../pages/start.ejs");
});
```

I get the console log:

```
id: serviceWorker.js
Req url: /serviceWorker.js
```

I tried breaking the request with break(), return, and next() but nothing worked. I have no service worker in my project which makes me wonder why it comes out of nowhere. Maybe I need som kind of service worker, or to specifically state somewhere in my project that it shouldn´t look for one?

Comment: Your route captures *everything*, so any GET request hitting your server will be triggered. Perhaps you want a more specific route?

Comment: Okay, reasonable. The thing is, I would like the API to work like this: When a new customer buys my product, their pages will be loaded into my database, and they get a specific URL, which corresponds to their table in the database. In this case, if their specific URL is "customer1", then their table in my db will be named "customer1", and this :id thing that takes everything would then be universal so that I wouldn´t have to make a new route for every customer. Did this make sense?

Comment: If you want all those to be handled at the root (so `/customer1`, then you need to call the `next()` function to ensure that other routes get a chance to handle paths that don't have a matching customer in the database. Plus you need to make sure that nobody can create a customer that overlaps with other routes you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you don't have a service worker in your project, there might still be one registered in your browser from a previous project that you ran on the same domain/IP address in the past.

The reason you are getting this request is that your browser no longer has the valid cached version of the service worker and tries to reload it. But since that request fails, it will try over and over again.

To remove it, open the website in question and check your browser developer tools (`Application -> Service Workers` or chrome and firefox), and unregister any service workers you no longer want to use.

Comment: Nice, unregistering worked like a charm, but now it tries to load a favicon instead. You don´t happen to have a quick fix for that as well? ;D

Comment: well, the only fix for that would be to actually serve the favicon. Another fix could be to specify a custom favicon URL in your `<head>` section but some browsers will still try to make that request even before the website loads. I would say that the best thing you can do is put `express.static` with the `fallthrough` option set before the API handler to serve any static content (like favicons, css, images, etc). Then in the API handler check if the `:id` exists in the database and if not then just return 404